# What is the right way to add pycharm to bin

Tags: authentication, path, exec, pycharm

I'm using `i3wm` on `arch` linux, and while try to run `pycharm` at first time there is kinda question to type my password
[image]
But password is right. I did same while tried to install other apps.

As far as I remember, there is no such problem using `xubuntu`.

`ln -s /usr/local/bin` won't take any effect.

I won't run `terminal` to run `pycharm`, and don't want to add whole folder to `$PATH`

[bugtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154690)

Answer (score 1):

Launch the IDE, then use Tools | Create Command-line Launcher.

Comment: Moved to bugtrack, will mark this post as solved, when solution would be found there